# Demonstrating the parallel axis theorem with double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

> The collection of lines parallel to the y-axis have the form $x =a$. Let $I=I_y$ be  the  usual moment  of  inertia around the y-axis $$I=\iint_R  x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA$$
>
> Let $\bar{I}$ be the moment of inertia around the axis $x=\bar x$, where $(\bar x, \bar y)$ is the center of mass. Show that $$I = \bar I + M \bar x^2$$

Here was my attempt:

$I = \bar I + M \bar x^2$ means $I - \bar I = M \bar x^2$. We compute the LHS below:

$$\iint_R  x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA - \iint_R  (x-\bar x)^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA$$

$$\iint_R  x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA - \bigg(\iint_R  x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA - \iint_R  2x\bar x \,  \delta \, \mathrm dA + \iint_R  \bar x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA \bigg )$$

$$\iint_R  2x\bar x \,  \delta \, \mathrm dA - \iint_R  \bar x^2 \delta \, \mathrm dA $$

$$\iint_R  (2x\bar x - \bar x^2)\,  \delta \, \mathrm dA $$

But I don't see why $\iint_R  (2x\bar x - \bar x^2)\,  \delta \, \mathrm dA = M \bar x^2$. Integrating with respect to $\mathrm dx \mathrm dy$ doesn't give me anything useful either. Did I make a mistake, or is there an intuitive property of $2x\bar x + \bar x^2$ that I fail to see?

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to use the formula for the center of mass. And also remember that $\bar x$ can be taken outside of the integral. $$\iint_R  (2x\bar x - \bar x^2)\,  \delta \, \mathrm dA=2\bar x \iint_R  x  \delta \, \mathrm dA-\bar x^2\iint_R \delta \, \mathrm dA$$
Now $$\iint_R \delta \, \mathrm dA=M$$ and $$\bar x=\frac{1}{M}\iint_R  x  \delta \, \mathrm dA$$
Therefore $$\iint_R  (2x\bar x - \bar x^2)\,  \delta \, \mathrm dA=2\bar x(\bar xM)-\bar x^2M=M\bar x^2$$